# Conditional probabilities: complements

Tags: probability

> In a particular community, 10% are dissatisfied with plumbing jobs. Half of the complaints were about plumber $A$, who does 40% of the plumbing jobs in the town. What is the probability that a consumer will obtain a satisfactory plumbing job, given that the plumber was $A$?

I named two events:

- $X$ is receiving an unsatisfactory plumbing job
- $Y$ is receiving $A$ as your plumber

I first calculated $P(X|Y) = \dfrac{1}{8}$. Now I want to calculate the probability they ask for, which using my events I reckon to be $P(X^C|Y)$.

$$P(X^c|Y) = \dfrac{P(Y|X^c)P(X^c)}{P(Y)} = \dfrac{P(Y|X^c) \cdot 0.9}{0.4}$$

But I don't really know how to obtain $P(Y|X^c)$. Can anybody chime in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just one step short of the answer.

$P(X^C|Y) = 1 - P(X|Y)$ for *any* $X$ and $Y$.